# How are asteroid monitors created?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-2

I've been playing Sword of the Stars II for a while now, and on this (Morrigi) playthrough I've unlocked and researched most of the Construction tech tree, including "monitor construction".

However, when I try to send a constructor fleet to a system I own that has an asteroid belt in it, I can't seem to find a "construct monitor" mission type either in the main tab or the "build station" screen.

After researching Mega Strip Mining I unlocked mining stations, which can be built automatically by civilians if you allocate stimulus money to mining.

**EDIT 2** Asteroid Monitors can now be designed and constructed the same way regular defense platforms are.

Comment: Good question; it _might_ just be “not yet implemented”. The game was released in a poor state and it's only gradually being patched into playability…

Comment: Turns out you need to research "mega strip mining" in order to be able to build mining stations, which then starts happening by civilian construction as well if you don't order it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent patches finally added them in. For future reference, once you've researched the technology they can be designed in the ship design screen with other defense platforms, but they can only be built in systems with at least one asteroid belt.